# aggregating nested SQL statements to fewer columns

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate my data and group it with respect to SKU's and the cluster ID associated with that SKU.

My current output brings back roughly 40,000 rows (5 SKU's * 8,000 Stores) however I want just 35.

My code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.*
FROM ALC_ITEM_SOURCE P
RIGHT JOIN
(
SELECT D.* ,SUM(L.ALLOCATED_QTY) AS TOTAL_ALLOCATED
FROM ALC_ITEM_LOC L
RIGHT JOIN 
(
SELECT C.*
FROM STORE S, 
(
SELECT A.*, B.LOCATION AS STORE_NUMBER
FROM FDT_MAP_CLUSTER_LOCATION B, 
(
SELECT DISTINCT SS.ALLOC_CLUSTER_ID, SS.ALLOC_CLUSTER_NAME, SS.SKU
from fdt_maptool_sas_data ss
WHERE SS.SKU IN (1099866,
1099896,
1000898,
1000960,
1000988 
)
AND SS.ORDER_NO IS NOT NULL
AND ALLOC_CLUSTER_NAME NOT LIKE '%DC Cluster%'
GROUP BY SS.ALLOC_CLUSTER_ID, SS.ALLOC_CLUSTER_NAME, SS.WORKSHEET_ID, SS.SKU
)A 
WHERE B.CLUSTER_ID = A.ALLOC_CLUSTER_ID
AND B.LOCATION_TYPE = 'S'
)C
WHERE S.STORE = C.STORE_NUMBER
AND S.STORE_CLOSE_DATE IS NULL
AND S.DISTRICT NOT IN (997, 998, 999)
AND S.STORE_OPEN_DATE <= SYSDATE
)D
ON L.ITEM_ID = D.SKU
AND L.LOCATION_ID = D.STORE_NUMBER

GROUP BY D.ALLOC_CLUSTER_ID, D.ALLOC_CLUSTER_NAME, D.SKU, D.STORE_NUMBER
)E
ON P.ITEM_ID = E.SKU
AND P.SOURCE_TYPE <> 4
AND P.RELEASE_DATE > '01-FEB-2018'
```

My desired result would contain:

```
SKU       Cluster_ID   Total_allocated  Count(stores) 
1000989    1AA STORES   258             200
1000989    2A STORES    78              600
1000989    B STORES     36              500
1000989    C STORES     114             100
1000989    D STORES     144             1222
1000989    E STORES     168             600
1000989    F STORES     60              501
```

Which is taking a sum of total allocated per store per cluster ID.

As you can see each SKU has a grade (AA-F), I would want to repeat this 5 times since I have 5 SKU's.

Basically I am asking how can I aggregate my data up to look like the above table from the 40,000 rows it is now.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make your sql nicer and neat, you should avoid constructing joins in 'where' statement.
Also I think you have nothing to do with ALC_ITEM_SOURCE table, since you did not use it practically.

You may try this version, or at least start working on it:

```
select SS.ALLOC_CLUSTER_ID,SS.ALLOC_CLUSTER_NAME,SS.SKU,SUM (L.ALLOCATED_QTY) as total_allocated,count(b.location) as store_number
FROM fdt_maptool_sas_data ss
inner join 
FDT_MAP_CLUSTER_LOCATION b on B.CLUSTER_ID =A.ALLOC_CLUSTER_ID AND B.LOCATION_TYPE = 'S'
inner join store s on S.STORE = b.location AND S.STORE_CLOSE_DATE IS NULL AND S.DISTRICT NOT IN (997, 998, 999) AND S.STORE_OPEN_DATE <= SYSDATE
left outer join ALC_ITEM_LOC L on L.ITEM_ID = ss.SKU AND L.LOCATION_ID = b.location
WHERE     SS.SKU IN (1099866,
                    1099896,
                    1000898,
                    1000960,
                    1000988)
        AND SS.ORDER_NO IS NOT NULL
        AND ALLOC_CLUSTER_NAME NOT LIKE '%DC Cluster%'
```